# What is the best way to write a wrapper function that runs commands and logs their exit code

Tags: bash, unix, shell

I currently use this function to wrap executing commands and logging their execution, and return code, and exiting in case of a non-zero return code.

However this is problematic as apparently, it does double interpolation, making commands with single or double quotes in them break the script.

Can you recommend a better way?

Here's the function:

```
do_cmd()
{
    eval $*
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
    then
        echo "Successfully ran [ $1 ]"
    else
        echo "Error: Command [ $1 ] returned $?"
        exit $?
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
"$@"
```

From http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters:

> @
>
> Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. When the
>   expansion occurs within double quotes, each parameter expands to a
>   separate word. That is, "$@" is equivalent to "$1" "$2" .... If the
>   double-quoted expansion occurs within a word, the expansion of the
>   first parameter is joined with the beginning part of the original
>   word, and the expansion of the last parameter is joined with the last
>   part of the original word. When there are no positional parameters,
>   "$@" and $@ expand to nothing (i.e., they are removed).

This means spaces in the arguments are re-quoted correctly.

```
do_cmd()
{
    "$@"
    ret=$?
    if [[ $ret -eq 0 ]]
    then
        echo "Successfully ran [ $@ ]"
    else
        echo "Error: Command [ $@ ] returned $ret"
        exit $ret
    fi
}
```

Comment: Of course, `cmd; if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then stuff` is more idiomatically written `if cmd; then stuff`.

Comment: But the code should use $ret later, so saving it is clearer IMHO.

Comment: I use this, slightly modified after https://stackoverflow.com/a/15383353/1172302 to capture the exit status of commands ran in child shells.

Answer (score 8):

Additional to `"$@"` what Douglas says, i would use

```
return $?
```

And not `exit`. It would exit your shell instead of returning from the function. If in cases you want to exit your shell if something went wrong, you can do that in the caller:

```
do_cmd false i will fail executing || exit
# commands in a row. exit as soon as the first fails
do_cmd one && do_cmd && two && do_cmd three || exit
```

(That way, you can handle failures and then exit gracefully).