# Pass variable from a child to parent in KSH

Tags: variables, fork, ksh, subroutine

I have to work with KSH (yeah that hell shell).
I need to use a fork, a subroutine as following:

```
    #!/bin/ksh

    PIPE=PIPE_$$
    PIPE_ERR=PIPE_ERR_$$

    export TEST_FILS

    $(. ./LanceFils.ksh 2>${PIPE_ERR} 1>${PIPE}) &
    PID_CHILD=$!
    echo "Nom du fichier PIPE: ${PIPE}"
    echo "Processus fils : " $!
    wait ${PID_CHILD}

    echo "Code retour: " $?
    echo "Sortie standard de PROC_FILS : " $(cat ${PIPE})
    echo "Sortie d'erreur(s) de PROC_FILS : " $(cat ${PIPE_ERR})

    echo "Contenu de TEST_FILS: ${TEST_FILS}"
    rm -rf ${PIPE}
```

Content of LanceFils.ksh

```
    #!/bin/ksh

    TIMEOUT=5

    export TEST_FILS

    echo "Je suis le script fils et j'attends ${TIMEOUT} secondes" 
    echo "Nom du pipe du pere ${PIPE}"
    sleep ${TIMEOUT}

    TEST_FILS="Je suis le fils"
    echo "Salut c'était bien !!!"
    exit 10
```

I know this do not work, btw i try to find a way to make it works ...
In my code you can see i want share TEST_FILS variable between child and parent.
There is way in KSH to share a variable, as in perl by using "share" or if i have to use a pipe like in C ?

Thank you.

Comment: That all depends on what ksh we're talking about and how decrepit it is. If it's modern piping around data-structures is cake. Otherwise you should probably look for an alternative to forking a subshell. Have a look at ksh coprocesses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Variables can be passed from a parent shell to child shell, not the other way around. However, you can do a workaround if you are really in need of the value set in the child shell.

One possible workaround: In the child shell, write the env variables of your interest along with their values to a file. Once you are back in the parent shell, run this file so that the env variables needed are overwritten with what is set in the file. You can [refer here](http://www.theunixschool.com/2010/07/how-to-access-child-shell-env-variable.html) for an example.

Comment: Thank you for helping, so i have to use C strategy to solve my problem. Btw "printenv" is a little bit dangerous, i prefer export variable one by one.

Answer (score 2):

A shell variable is just a piece of memory inside the running shell process. An Environment Variable is a variable that the shell copies into its *environment* prior to calling another program.

To understand the limitations of Environment Variables, one must understand the concept of the *environment* of a process: It's a single section of memory that is not *shared* between processes, but *passed on* from one process to another during an [`exec`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/exec.3.html) system call.
(See also: [Environment Variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17758/exception-of-inheritance-of-environment-variables))

The environment gets passed on from one process to the next, and subsequent processes can change it prior to calling another program.

This environment also has certain restrictions: It can consist only of a list of nul-terminated strings, terminated by a null-pointer.  Essentially, it's an array of strings.

Note that these strings do not need to follow the `VARNAME=value` structure, which is a convention adopted by early unix shells.

`ksh93` does support shell *co-processes*, though.

After starting a child process, the parent can connect to the child's stdin and stdout with the `<& p` and `>& p` redirection operators.  It can be a challenge to handle these correctly, as many operations close their stdout on termination, which will close the pipe to the child.

Comment: Thanks for helping, btw i know what is an environment and i know how variables scopes works. Maybe its gonna help someone else ...

Keep thinking trap stdin/stdout may be dangerous because of syntax error catching ... i prefer use Guru's solution because its safer than this one.

Comment: Guru's solution is safe and simple.  I just wanted to make sure that it's more than just scope - it's a different address space, and the data only flows one way.  As IPC goes, it's a pipe or a file for shells.  And with ksh93, a socket might just work as well.