# Bash: share variables between functions calls

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a script with some functions that is loaded in the beginning of other scrips to do the common work. To avoid reprocess, I'm trying to create some kinda *cache* with some script scope variables. So this is my problem:

supposing I have this scripts:

*functions.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash
v_cache=

set_cache()
{
    v_cache=1
    echo 1
}
echo_cache()
{
    echo "v_cache=$v_cache"
}
```

*test.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash
. function.sh

var=`set_cache`
echo_cache

set_cache
echo_cache
```

Here is the output:

```
$ ./test.sh 
v_cache=
1
v_cache=1
```

Calling a function in an attribution (either with `*func*` or $(*func*)) have different context than a simple call. I need to keep the same scope  to all functions calls in the same script (*test.sh* for example).

For the example above, the output I was expecting is:

```
$ ./test.sh 
v_cache=1
1
v_cache=1
```

I tried to find some explanation for why it works this way, but can't found nothing. I think `` trigger a new *bash* execution, completely independent.

There's a way to share a variable through all functions calls? What are the alternatives to bypass this behaviour?

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15541321/2088135

Answer (score 1):

The "unexpected" behavior is because of subshell creation with `` or $() at this line.

```
var=`set_cache`
```

When the subshell kicks off, it creates it's own variable called v_cache, sets it to 1, and echo's 1 back to set var in the parent shell.  Then the subshell exits, and you echo v_cache (of the oringal/parent shell), which is unset.

There are different trains of thought with function, from my background and languages, you should never use a function to change a global, you should instead have it return a value for the global.  In this case, change your var to v_cache.  Other people (who must have a different background than me) feel this is a short coming of bash.

Answer (score 0):

If you call function.sh by ./function.sh in test.sh, a sub shell will be launched to run funtion.sh, so the variable value will not be kept in the shell which test.sh is running.

You should call function.sh by *source ./function.sh* to run them in the same shell.

Comment: `.` (used in the question) and `source` behave identically in bash. Questioner didn't write `./function.sh` they wrote `. function.sh`.

Comment: @Julian, thx for your comment, I have not known the syntax of .  function.sh in shell script by now,  i will investigate it.