# Is there is a way of sourcing csh file in tcl script and bringing variables to the main shell?

Tags: tcl, csh, tcsh

I'm trying to source a some.cshrc during TCL script execution. 
I get no error but the variables set in some.cshrc are not passed back to the shell.

When writing it like:
**source some.cshrc**
I'm getting an error.
Then I tried: 
**exec /bin/csh -c "source some.cshrc"**

Please advise

Comment: It's a completely different language. That's… really very tricky. What was the error message?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set a parent shell's variable from a subshell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541321/set-a-parent-shells-variable-from-a-subshell)

Comment: You can not set a variable in the parent process from a child process.

Comment: How complex is the process of setting those variables? If it's simply `set x=y`, then you can read the file in Tcl and parse out the values. If it's more complex, like using backticks, then you'll have to spawn a csh, source the file, and print out the variable/value pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Csh and Tcl are two completely different languages, you cannot simply load a Csh file in a Tcl script via a `source` command.

You can think of a workaround instead. Let us assume you want to load all the variables set with a `setenv` command. Example contents of `some.cshrc` file could look something like this:

```csh
setenv EDITOR vim
setenv TIME_STYLE long-iso
setenv TZ /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Warsaw
```

You can write a Tcl script which reads this file line by line and searches for `setenv` commands. You can then reinterpret the line as a list and set an appropriate variable in a global namespace via an `upvar` command.

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh

proc load_cshrc {file_name} {
  set f [open $file_name r]
  while {[gets $f l] >= 0} {
    if {[llength $l] == 3 && [lindex $l 0] eq "setenv"} {
      upvar [lindex $l 1] [lindex $l 1]
      set [lindex $l 1] [lindex $l 2]
    }
  }
  close $f
}

load_cshrc "some.cshrc"
puts "EDITOR = $EDITOR"
puts "TIME_STYLE = $TIME_STYLE"
puts "TZ = $TZ"
```

Please note, that since we do not run a Csh subshell any variable substitutions in the Csh script would not occur.

Comment: Thank you, looks like this is the best way to parse all required csh commands this way.